# Using an element as the base point for selecting other elements?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Say we have the following divs. If, for example, the third *item* in the second *row* is clicked on, is possible to be able to select any other *item* divs with some kind of nth selector, even if they are in other *row*, based on the clicked *item* as a start point?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"...select any other item divs with some kind of nth selector..."*

Well you can use the [`:nth-child()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) to get all elements that are an nth child of their own parent, in combination with the [`.index()` method](http://api.jquery.com/index/) which (called with no arguments) will tell you the index of the clicked item relative to its siblings.

A simple example of that is as follows:

```
var $items = $(".item").click(function () {
    $items.removeClass("selected")
          .filter(":nth-child(" + ($(this).index() + 1) + ")")
          .addClass("selected");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HPptK/

Note that the `.index()` method gives you a zero-based index but `:nth-child()` counts from one.

My simple example selects all nth items including the clicked one, but you can use the [`.not()` method](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exlude it if desired (in my example above you'd add `.not(this)` after the `.filter()`).

Comment: Thanks! Got rid of the rows in the end and just floated them all in the same container. :nth-child() was good for it then :)